# The "contacts" menu in magento configuration under general is missing

Tags: magento-1.9, system.xml, contact-us, system-config

The "contacts" menu in my magento 1.9 configuration under general tab is missing. Can anyone help me understand why it is missing and where can i find it?

Comment: phpFan,Suggestion to be  track magento Exception and system.log.And put log at here

Answer (score 0):

Have a look under Configuration > Advanced > Advanced and make sure Mage_Contacts is still enabled:

[image]

Alternatively you may have module that is overriding it and removing it, check for any contact modules that could be rewriting the core.